# Windows: Child Process with Redirected Input and Output

Tags: windows, process, io, pipe

I'm trying to create a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output (as described here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499(VS.85).aspx).

> For the people that don't want to bother reading the source code on that page, the author is using anonymous pipes to redirect the child's input and output. The parent process writes to the child process's input and reads from the child process's output.

In that code however, the program is closing the pipes after reading and writing (in WriteToPipe and ReadFromPipe), so actually the program just reads a file, dumps it on the child process input stream and then reads the child process response.

Now, what I'm looking for is a code where we will not close the pipes, but we will continuously post requests and read the child process response (in contrast to making just 1 request).

I've tried several modifications to the source code given on the link posted above, but no matter what I try, the program always hangs when calling ReadFile() in the ReadFromPipe() function (it probably waits for the child to quit - but as I said I like to get the child response, and then send other requests to it).

Any ideas on how I can get over this?

#### Update:

Can anyone at least tell me whether using the .NET Process class with `RedirectStandardInput` and `RedirectStandardOutput` is a good option?

Comment: The sample code and documentation seem to indicate that you have to close the write handle to prevent ReadFile() from hanging.  I think I did something like this before, but it was long ago and I can't remember the details.

Comment: @Luke's right, specifically, all copies of the write handle have to be closed, either explicitly via `CloseHandle()` or implicitly via the process exiting.

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly the same problem, and solved it by using `PeekNamedPipe` (which according to MSDN is also fine for anonymous read pipes) to check for available data before each call to ReadFile. That removed the blocking issues I was getting, and allowed my `GetExitCodeProcess()` to see that the process had exited and cleanup the pipes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - the .Net Process class redirects the standard input / output of the child process with anonymous pipes in a very similar way to the linked sample if you use `RedirectStandardInput` and `RedirectStandardOutput`, so this is probably a fairly good option.

As for why `ReadFile` is hanging - it sounds like this function is waiting for the child process to either send some data back, or to close the pipe.  If you want to continuously post requests to the child process then you need to either:

- **Know exactly when it is appropriate to read** so that you are not left waiting / blocked for the child process (so for example you only read immediately after a request has been sent).  This strategy is very risky as there is always a chance that the child process doesn't behave as expected and you are left waiting on the child process indefinitely.
- **Have a dedicated thread for reading** - if you have a dedicated thread for reading then it doesn't matter that the thread may wait indefinitely for the child process as your other threads are still able to send requests and operate as normal.  This method is more complex than the first option, however when done properly is far more robust.  The only other drawback to this approach is that it requires you have an additional read thread for each child process, meaning that it doesn't scale very well if you need to communicate with a large number of child processes.
- **Use asynchronous IO** - It is possible to call the [ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in a way such that it always immediately returns, however notifies you when a read has completed (I'm a little fuzzy on the exact details on how this works as I'm more used to C#).  This is know as [Asynchronous IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365683%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and is the most versatile of these 3 methods as it allows you to communicate with many child processes without needing a dedicated thread for each one.  The tradeoff however is that it is also the most complex to do correctly (at least in my opinion).